# Does NOP affect the status registers in Intel x86 architecture?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have recently noticed that `NOP` instruction in Intel x86 assembly is actually same as `XCHG EAX, EAX` 
 Won't that bring about unexpected results by altering the status registers ?
For example, if `EAX` was initially zero, then the sixth bit of `FLAG` register ( the Zero Bit ) would be set after a `NOP`.

So how is it safe to use `NOP` in my code ?

Comment: `XCHG` doesn't modify any flags.

Comment: XCHG is of form `xchg regA, regB`, where regA == regB is an exception, not the norm. Logically, what would be the target register in that case? From which register the Flags should be set accordingly? Because no answer can be given, flags are not modified at all. And because of that, xchg ax,ax can be used to encode single byte NOP. (and e.g. xchg bx,bx can be used to encode two byte NOP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A random x86 reference](http://www.fermimn.gov.it/linux/quarta/x86/xchg.htm) easily explains this, by stating for the `XCHG` instruction:

> Flags Affected
>
> None

Answer (score 3):

NOP (or XCHG, or MOV) does not change FLAGS register in x86 architecture. To use NOP is always safe. (And how it could be different?)